# Migrating cordova app from Google Maps to OSM

Tags: google-maps, cordova, openstreetmap

I need some directions.  My mobile app is heavily dependent on Google Maps for the the following components: maps, geocoding/geolocation, autocomplete, distanceMatrix and directionsMatrix.  However, I am running into quota issues and they are getting worse and worse.  I need an as reliable solution but without the quotas and am considering OSM.  I have my own api unix server I can install OSM too but I am having a hard time finding a complete install package.

Everything I read is separate packages to install and configure for each of the components I need to migrate to.  Is there not a comprehensive OSM package that has all of the components built into it?  I keep thinking there should be a single package that is all integrated to work together but I can't find one.

If one exists please point me in the right direction.  If one doesn't can you please recommend the best, and easiest to use, OSM packages that meet my listed of required components?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

OSM consists of several components. First there is the map data which can be seen as raw data, no software involved. Depending on your goals you will likely need a database software, which is usually postgresql. For drawing a map you will need a renderer, for address searching a geocoder, for directions a routing software and so on.

- Showing a map: Use one of the available [tile providers](https://switch2osm.org/providers/) or [render your own tiles](https://switch2osm.org/serving-tiles/)
- Geocoding: Take a look at [Nominatim](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim) or [Photon](http://photon.komoot.de/). Photon is based on Nomatim and adds some features, most importantly autocompletion. There are other [search engines](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Search_engines) available as well.
- Routing: [GraphHopper](http://graphhopper.com/) or [OSRM](http://project-osrm.org/). More alternatives available, check the list of [OSM online routers](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing/online_routers).

Similarly to tile servers, most of these softwares can be either run by yourself or accessed via various online providers. Online providers usually have quotas whereas running your own software is solely limited by your own resources.

Comment: thanks for the response.  Based on your response it appears that there is no just one simple package to replace google.  Its going to be a combination of various packages.  Do these packages interact with each other, use each others resources or are they all independent?

Comment: Usually they are independent from each other. They require roughly the same data but with different database schemes, thus accessing different databases.